# slider with autoplay and next and previous arrows with CSS HTML JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner and I'd like to know if it's possible to create a responsive slider with autoplay(fade or slide effect, no matters) and next and previous arrows for navigation without affecting the autoplay, just to change from one slide to another.

I've already tried with multiple js solutions I found on the net like "setinterval" function with javascript, but I have always the same problem, one effect works and not the other.

Actually I've done a slider in html and css but I can't get this done by adding a javascript function.

I am open to all the solutions, even if it is possible only with js.

I'm following a course right now and that is part of a project.

could it be done??

Thank you in advance!

```css
    /*progress bar effect*/

    @keyframes loading {
      0% {
        transform: scaleX(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: scaleX(100%);
      }
    }

    /*autoplay effect*/
    @keyframes fade {
      0% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      45% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      95% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }

    @keyframes fade2 {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      45% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      95% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }


    /*Section slider*/

    .slider {
      width: 100%;
      height: 550px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      position: relative;
    }

    .slide1,
    .slide2 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .slide1 {
      background: url('images/bg1.jpg') no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
      animation: fade 30000s infinite linear;
      -webkit-animation: fade 30000s infinite linear;
    }

    .slide2 {
      background: url('images/bg2.jpg') no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
      animation: fade2 30000ms infinite linear;
      -webkit-animation: fade2 30000ms infinite linear;
    }


    /*progress bar*/

    .progress-bar {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -76px;
      left: 0px;
      height: 80px;
      width: 100%;
      background: color: rgba(192, 194, 192, 0.8);
      border-radius: 0 0 1px 1px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 14px -10px #737373, inset 0px -11px 8px -10px #CCC;
    }

    .loaded {
      height: 4px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #5cadd3;
      animation: 15000ms infinite linear loading normal;
      transform-origin: 0%;
    }


    /*Slider buttons left or right*/

    .slider #button_left {
      position: absolute;
      top: 45%;
      left: 0px;
      background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.6);
      width: 35px;
      height: 70px;
      border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
    }

    .slider #button_right {
      position: absolute;
      top: 45%;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.6);
      width: 35px;
      height: 70px;
      border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
    }

    #button_left:hover,
    #button_right:hover {
      transition: .3s;
      background-color: rgba(99, 99, 99, 1);
      color: #ffffff;
    }


    /*left and right arrows for slider with font-awesome*/

    .fas.fa-chevron-left {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 30%;
      margin-left: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 25px;
    }

    .fas.fa-chevron-right {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 30%;
      margin-right: 5px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
```

```html
    <section id="slideshow">
      <div class='slider'>
        <div class='slide1'>
          <div class="text-slider">
            <h1><span class="textblue">WEBAGENCY</span>: lorem ipsum <br> lorem ipsum</h1>
            <p> lorem ipsum</p>
            <a href="#"> lorem ipsum</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='slide2'>
          <div class="text-slider">
            <h1><span class="textblue">WEBAGENCY</span>: lorem ipsum <br> lorem ipsum</h1>
            <p> lorem ipsum</p>
            <a href="#services"> lorem ipsum</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="progress-bar"></div>-->
        <div class="progress-bar">
          <div class="loaded"></div>
        </div>
        <a href="images/bg1.jpg" id="button_left"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a href="images/bg2.jpg" id="button_right"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </section>
```

[image: Slider]

Comment: you can try carousel by bootstrap-4 : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: @Francico Use Bootstrap framework  or else refer OwlCarousel

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that I can't use bootstrap because this is a project  for my course and I am not allowed to use bootstrap, only css3 html5 and javascript in order to add a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a lib or framework to do that.
So, i already have to do this, it's not as complicated as it seems. 
First, i used css pseudo class :checked and input type radio to choose which slide to display:

```
<div id="slider">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" checked> <!-- The first slide is displayed by default -->
    <div class="slide">...</div>

    <input type="radio" name="slider">
    <div class="slide">...</div>
    ...

    <div class="prev-button">prev</div>
    <div class="next-button">next</div>
</div>
```

And a bit of css :

```
#slider > .slide,
#slider > input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
}
#slider > input[type="radio"]:checked + .slide{display:block;}
```

Then, it should be simpler with js:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    let timer; let delay = 4000;
    let loader = document.querySelector("#slider .loader");
    let inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#slider > input[type="radio"]'));
    //first, the go function that choose which input to check
    let go = (prev=false)=>{
        let checked = document.querySelector('#slider > input[type="radio"]:checked');
        let index = inputs.indexOf(checked);

        let next = ((prev) ? index -1 : index + 1);
        if(next >= inputs.length) next = 0; //restart from beginning
        else if(next < 0 ) next = inputs.length -1; //go to the last slide

        //restart the progress bar
        loader.classList.remove("loader");
        loader.classList.add("loader");
        inputs[next].checked = true;

    };
    //Allow you to define some sort of recursive timeout, otherwise it works only once
    let defineTimer = (callback)=>{
        timer = setTimeout(()=>{
            callback();
            defineTimer(callback);
        },delay);
    };
    //next, autoplay :
    defineTimer(go);

    //next, buttons:
    let next = document.querySelector("#slider > .next-button");
    let prev = document.querySelector("#slider > .prev-button");

    //clear the timer with `clearTimeout` each time you click on a button, if you don't 
    //and the user click on a button 3900ms after the autoplay call, the next/prev slide will only be displayed 
    //for 100ms and then switch to the next, which can be disturbing for the user.
    next.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        go();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        defineTimer(go);
    });
    prev.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        go(true);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        defineTimer(go);
    });
});
```

Why it should works : 
Every time the `go` function is called, it will select the next or previous input to check, accordingly to the currently checked one. So you can call it from the timer or not, it doesn't makes any difference.

Hope it answer your question :)

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately I could not make this work as you mentioned, maybe I am forgetting something.

Comment: The buttons are not calling any slide and there is not autoplay either.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't have the time to test when i wrote it, there was effectively two problems, that are now fixed.
I edited my answer accordingly, and tested it, it should works.

Comment: Thank you very much! that's great. Just in case do you know if it is possible to restart the progress bar when the arrows are clicked?

Comment: You should accept the answer if this fullfill your requirements ^^ 

What kind of progression do you want to display ? 
You should put the associated code inside the go() function, as you get the index in the `next` var, it allow you to you to do something like `document.querySelector("#slider .loader").innerHTML=next +1;` that will display the number of the slide that is currently displayed

Comment: Thanks again for your answer
 I think I'll leave like that because I do not handle javascript yet.
On the other hand, I have a problem, once I resize the screen the right button and the progress bar are coming before the slider, is not very responsive. 
Do you know how I could handle this without the "overflow:hidden" in the slider? 
I just need to make all things, slider and its content, to resize together and I can't find a solution, I did not find it on the net. Any advice would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forget what i told you about refreshing progress bar, as i didn't tried your code yet I didn't notice the css animation ^^ I edit my answer.
For your responsive problem, see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)